# Magento install ubuntu

Tags: magento, ubuntu

Im having problem installing Magento on ubuntu. I've created and a2ensite a site with a documentroot that points to the "installation files" I've dowloaded from magento SVN repository. I've testes localhost and it works. This is my virtualhost file under sites-available and its present in sites-enabled aswell.

My virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin magento@localhost.com
ServerName magento.localhost.com
DocumentRoot /srv/www/magento_dev/public_html

<Directory /srv/www/magento_dev/public_html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog /srv/www/magento_dev/logs/error.log
LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that I can't connec to the site when I type magento.localhost.com
I understand that there are a lot of things that can be wrong here but I've doubled checked everything e.g. the doucment root is there at /srv/www/magento_dev/public_html and the site is enabled and apache2 is reloaded.

Comment: Definitely will be wrong URL localhost.com right format is http://localhost/something/...etc

Comment: Did you check your permissions for the site? Try 777 for everything just to be sure.And then apply  the correct permissions.

Answer (score 2):

The url you are using seems to be wrong. Try with `http://localhost:80/magento`.